# Heuristics for this "subset" traveling salesman problem

Tags: graph-theory, oc.optimization-and-control, approximation-algorithms, heuristics

Are there any known heuristics for the following variation of the traveling salesman problem:  given $n$ sets of points $S_1,\dots,S_n$, and $n$ integers $k_i$ such that $k_i \leq |S_i|$, find the shortest path that visits $k_i$ points from each $S_i$?  The case $k_i=1$ is reasonably well-studied but I have not seen this variant.